# React array.slice multiple endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slice

Is it possible to get first 3 and last 2 items using array.slice in js

I want to render all data if user is AUTH, and if not I want first 3 and last 2 from array without recreating array.

```
 {menu.slice(...(auth ? [0, 5] : //THERE SHOULD FIND FIRST 3 AND LAST 2 )).map((item) => (
      <Link
        onClick={() => dispatch(handleMenu())}
        to={item.path}
        className={`${auth === false && "font-md"} ${
          item.path === window.location.pathname && "font-2xl"
        }`}
      >
        {item.title}
      </Link>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get first 3 items and last 2 items;

**example:**

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "d", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
```

**To get first 3 items:**

```
arr.slice(0, 3);
```

**To get last 2 items:**

```
arr.slice(-2);
```

As you wanted to add both of the slices and render them, this might help you:

```
arr.slice(0, 3).concat(arr.slice(-2));
```

Comment: My I didnt ask right. I want to render first 3 and last 2 in same time. Example arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], I want to print [1,2,3] and [8,9]

Comment: Then add the results together: `const toBeRendered = [...arr.slice(0, 3), ...arr.slice(-2)]`

Comment: For that you just have to use console log to print or you can put them in separate variables. then you will be able to reuse them.